# What database should I use in order to store highscores and users information from my app I want to publish on GooglePlay Store?

Tags: java, database, cordova, google-play

I am making a cross-platform mobile game with `Js, HTML, CSS, and Cordova`.
 First I want to compile it for Android and place it on `GooglePlay` Market. The thing is that I can not find information on the ways to store data from my game, like high scores, users etc.
I mean I couldn't find any information about Google's requirements on this matter, before you submit the game package to them for validation.
It is not clear, shall I use `Firebase` or I can use any DB server or a shall make a local file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Firebase if you are planning any kind of notification service on your application. if you are expecting heavy customer transactions then go for AWS.depending on your use case ,You can either choose AWS Relational data base service or NoSql service.

AWS RDS : https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

AWS NoSql : https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/

Data would be more secure, scalable and high availablity.